# Вопрос с array.map()

Tags: javascript

Выходеит ошибка   Line 11:21:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

```
import React from 'react'
import Task from '../task/Task'


export default function(props){
    console.log("props of wraper ", props)
    if(props.countOfTasks.length > 1){
        return(
            <div>
                {props.countOfTasks.map((task, index)=>{
                    <Task nameOfTask={props.task.nameTask} startAt={props.task.startAt}/>
                })}
            </div>
                
       
        )
    }else{
        return(
            <Task nameOfTask={props.countOfTasks[0].nameTask} startAt={props.countOfTasks[0].startAt}/>
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: На первый взгляд видно, что Вы забыли написать return  в обходе массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите возвращать `Task`, но не делаете этого.

```
{props.countOfTasks.map((task, index) => {
  return <Task nameOfTask={props.task.nameTask} startAt={props.task.startAt}/>
})}
```

Или же, используя фишку стрелочной функции:

```
{props.countOfTasks.map((task, index) => (
  <Task nameOfTask={props.task.nameTask} startAt={props.task.startAt}/>
))}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, это уже вторая ваша помощь за день, может если у вас есть время поможете в третий раз?  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143522